# How to insert into a record into a table created in VM MySQL Server from host OS?

Tags: mysql, azure-virtual-machine

First of all, I have to say that I created a VM through Microsoft Azure and then installed MySQL 5.5 setup on my VM and then followed the steps below:

create a database name it as yourname_HospitalDB and then create a table in it call it patients, the table should have the following attributes.
patID, patName, and age.
Now, go ahead and create a user in the database, name it as your name and give any password to him/her, also grant the insert privileges to this user on the patient table. NOW, from the host OS where you should have also installed a copy of MySQL server or client, log in with the user that you have created in VM MySQL Server. from here insert a record to the patient table that you have created in the VM MySQL server.

I did all of the above steps; I created a user and granted all privileges then I opened MySQL on my host OS and there when I want to log into the user I created on my VM it shows error.
The code that I used to access the user I created using VM from my host OS:

> mysql -u sediqa -p -h 52.188.171.252 -p3389;
> The error:
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u sediqa -p -h 52.188.171.252 -p3389' at line 1

Note: sediqa is the database user I created on MySQL through VM, 52.188.171.252 is the IP of the VM and 3389 is the portal

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is in the last p that should be uppercase and possibly space separated from the port number, like

mysql -u sediqa -p -h 52.188.171.252 -P 3389

mysql -u {username} -p'{password}' -h {remote server ip or name} -P {port}

More references for 8.0 at link:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-options.html

Answer (score 0):

P for port number should be capital letter P. as per below syntax

> mysql -u `USER` -p `PASSWORD` -h `IP/HOSTNAME` -P `PORT NUMBER`

in your input command need to change with below:

> mysql -u sediqa -p -h 52.188.171.252 -P3389